# Remove hidden element with :hidden selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and I try to remove an hidden element with `display: none;`

I want to use the `remove()` method of jquery to do so.

```
var id = "#container" + event.parentNode.id;
$('id[style*="display: none;"]').remove();
```

or

```
var id = "#container" + event.parentNode.id;
$('id:hidden"]').remove();
```

Both doesn't work for me.

I don't exactly know how to write the selector for the hidden element.

Comment: `console.log(id)` will show you what that variable actually contains. Go read up on the basics of working with strings and variables in JS after that.

Comment: `$(selector).filter(':hidden').remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove()` function of jquery, removes the element completely. If you wish to display or hide element use `show()` or `hide()` which will add display: block; or display: none;

As there is also question for hidden selector, to write hiden selector you would use `:hiden` at the end of elements you want to select. So in your case it might looke like this:

```
var id = '#container' + event.parentNode.id;
$(id+':hidden"]').show();
```

There is another issue with your selector. As elements which has ID set should be present on your page only once, therefore I don't see any point in this scenario why you need hidden selector.

Comment: I want to remove it completely, just have a problem with getting the ID.

Comment: I have adjusted my response with hidden selector. I'm not sure if variable id is pointing to correct results, but in most cases you won't do it this way as elements with ID whould be present on your page only once.

Comment: I know, I just want to remove one element, that's why I target it by the id.
But with pure JS I didn't get to remove the element cause it's display: none..

Comment: All right, than you don't need :hidden element at all as jquery is "targeting" hidden elements as well by default. You just need to select it with $(id).remove(); If it's not working, your id isn't probably targeting correctly.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you! I'll try it out. :)

Comment: No problem. If you have any more questions, ask here. Otherwise mark my answer as correct one. Thanks!

Comment: `"'#container' + event.parentNode.id"` that is one strange selector, think you might have a few more quotes than you wanted.

Comment: Yes, I tried to point out few times that his selector probably isn't working :)

Comment: Yea, I recognized it right after asking. Also changed it. ^^